# cordova-plugin-media-with-compression: resumeRecord is not working in android

Tags: android, ios, cordova, phonegap-build

I am using cordova-plugin-media-with-compression plugin.

I am running following code:

```
var test = new Media('test.wav');
test.startRecord();
test.pauseRecord();
test.resumeRecord();
test.stopRecord();
test.release();
test.play();
```

It plays only portion of recording after resume. It does not merge before resume and after resume sounds in Android. 
However it works perfectly in iOS.

Did someone also face such issue? 
And what can be the possible solution to fix this issue?

I am using PhoneGap Build to build apps.

Comment: Looking at the Native Android code for this plugin, it appears to be a fair bit behind the official Cordova-Media plugin, and does not include some code that merges files between pauses in the recording. I am working on merging the two, and will provide a pull request in the next few days.